# How do I determine the number of times my system has booted within a time period?

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10

I am running a few tests on a windows CPU where it periodically turns on and off. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to determine the number of times the system has booted successfully within a certain time period using the existing OS tools.

Comment: Related question on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/278012/how-to-find-out-how-often-windows-seven-has-rebooted